# What does "The intention is that each answer shall contain one and only one loophole" mean?

Tags: discussion, support

I want to know briefly about this statement:

> ["The intention is that each answer shall contain one and only one loophole"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)

Does this means we are allowed to use one loophole (of any kind) in one answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not allowed to use any loopholes.

"Answer" in that sentence refers to answers to that very meta post. The sentence simply means that *when answering the linked meta post* that you should only propose one loophole in your answer, so that loopholes can be voted on independently.

Comment: Oh!! my bad, don't have an English mother-tongue. :p

Answer (score 1):

That post is a list of things that are *not allowed* in answers by default. This is because these are things that have already been done before and they just aren't funny anymore.

The way that post works, is if you think a certain loophole should be banned, you post it as an answer on that thread. Then, other users will vote on it to see if they agree it should be banned. The phrase

> "The intention is that each answer shall contain one and only one loophole"

Means you should only propose a single loophole to be banned. If you were to propose multiple loopholes in a single answer, other users might agree with one loophole but not the other. This way, voting is easier.